# how to toggle a button in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the code is working but it has a bug that if you first add a item and go to the modal it will show first the disabled button before the enable if you go back to the item

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.container1").click(function(){
            $('#show_cart').load('temp_user_cart.php');
            if ($("table#dataTable tbody").length) {
                $("#deleteButton").attr("disabled", false);
                console.log(true);
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes because the click is eventually happening on the div itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your suggestion and insight, I already solve the problem by using php

```
<div class="" style="text-align: center; ">
 <div class="pl-2 pr-2 pt-3 pb-0" style="display:inline-block;border: 2px solid black; border-radius:5px; ">
  <?php
  $sqlbd = "SELECT SUM(item_total) AS SUB_TOTAL FROM temp_cart WHERE temp_id = '".$_SESSION['temp_id']."' ";
  $resultbd = $conn->query($sqlbd);
  while($rowbd = $resultbd->fetch_assoc()){
    if ($rowbd['SUB_TOTAL'] == 0) {
      ?><p style="color: green; ">EMPTY CART</p>
      <?php
    }else{
      ?><p style="color: green; "> ₱  <?php echo $rowbd['SUB_TOTAL'];  ?>.00</p>
      <?php
    }
    ?>

  </div>
</div>
<?php 
if($rowbd['SUB_TOTAL'] == 0){
  ?>
  <div style="text-align:right;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <a href="check-out.php">
        <button type="button" id="deleteButton" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="disabled">Go to cart</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}else{
  ?>
  <div style="text-align:right;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
      <a href="check-out.php">
        <button type="button" id="deleteButton" class="btn btn-primary">Go to cart</button>
      </a>
    </div>
    </div><?php 
  }
}
?>
```